# publish_pages and manage_pages approved in app review but not working

Tags: facebook, sdk

My app have been approved by the Facebook team 2 days ago (very fast approved: submitting 3 days ago) for publish_pages and manage_pages , and i still get 'this does not let the app to post facebook' on login page `(scope='publish_actions')`

Comment: You should not ask for publish_pages or publish_actions when the user logs in. You should ask him when you need it

Comment: _“and i still get 'this does not let the app to post facebook' on login page”_ – it always says that on the _first_ page of the login dialog; publishing permissions are only asked for on the _second_ screen – are you sure you did go that far?

Comment: there is no more permission displayed when i click on 'edit the info you provide' (only email and public profil,  checked)

Answer (score 0):

The login flow works like this - 
Initially you see a basic info dialog - https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t39.2178-6/851546_620507588026124_290281089_n.png
Additionally publishing permissions (publish_actions) will prompt a second step in the Login dialog - https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t39.2178-6/851557_535801936465660_169463870_n.png
You can see a working example with the below login integration - 
https://www.spotify.com/sg-en/signup/?forward_url=%2Fsg-en%2Fdownload%2Fmac%2F

Comment: Upload photo directly to answer above photo url showing access denied.